# List Reports on Same Page, Same Query But Different Parameters

Tags: list, parameters, report

I am using Cognos 10.  Is there a way to create 2 different list reports on the same page, using the same query, but changing a parameter between the 2 list reports to produce 2 different results?  In other words, and for example, I want to produce a sales report with 2 lists and the same data, but 1 list would feature 1 country, and the other list would feature a different country, but on the same page and using the same single query.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this but I believe the easiest way is to section your list.

Here are the basic steps to section a list:

1. Add the columns you want to a list, including the column you want to vary for each list
2. Select the column that you want to be different for each list
3. Select Section/Unsection from the Structure menu or use the associated toolbar button

When you run the report a list will be generated for each unique value in the sectioned column.